# Assign two variables via generator expression w/ conditional?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, generator-expression

The below code has a dictionary containing various cheeses, as well as their quantities. Based off a pre-determined list of sale items, the code then prints the total quantity of cheeses which are on sale versus full price.

I'm using generator expressions to calculate the totals, but I'm wondering if there's a way to condense my code to assign both the `sale_count` and `full_price_count` variables at once with some sort of if-else condition, as the code for the generators is practically the same.

```
cheeses = {'gouda': 3, 'cheddar': 7, 'american': 2, 'mozzarella': 5}
on_sale = ['american', 'blue cheese', 'cheddar', 'provolone', 'swiss']

# if the cheese is on sale, add its quantity to sale_count
# otherwise, add its quantity to full_price_count
sale_count = sum(qty for (cheese, qty) in cheeses.items() if cheese in on_sale)
full_price_count = sum(qty for (cheese, qty) in cheeses.items() if cheese not in on_sale)

print("Sale count: {}\nFull price count: {}".format(sale_count, full_price_count))
```

Comment: Not really. However decreasing line count shouldn't be the goal of cleaning up code. That looks like good, clear code. It's obvious what each part is doing. If you're worried about speed, your biggest improvement would be to switch `on_sale` from a list to a Set.

Comment: If you really have a massive amount of data, instead of iterating over the dictionary twice, iterate over it once leveraging if else conditions and 'then' at the end sum the resulting lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done in a single expression as:

```
functools.reduce(
    lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]),
    ((qty, 0) if cheese in on_sale else (0, qty) for cheese, qty in cheeses.items()), 
    (0, 0))
```

But then this, as with other potential answers, might really answer why things **don't always have to be simplified into one expression when two is perfectly clear.**

Answer (score 0):

It is not very readable, but it does what you want in one line:

```
[sale_count, full_price_count] = map(sum, zip(*[(qty, 0) if cheese in on_sale else (0, qty) for cheese, qty in cheeses.items()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is the following, but I agree with @donkopotamus, if you don't have performance concerns, wo expressions are ok.

```
sale_count, full_price_count  = map(sum, zip(*((v * (c in on_sale), v * (c not in on_sale)) for c, v in cheeses.items())))
```